# Tkinter and show from pyplot issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Here is context:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

#####################
#  MOUSE CLICK      #
#####################

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    cadre.append(eclick.xdata)
    cadre.append(eclick.ydata)
    cadre.append(erelease.xdata)
    cadre.append(erelease.ydata)

def toggle_selector(event):
    print (' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['enter', 'Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print ('Selection done ')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
        pl.close()


###########
#  Input  #
###########
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [("Image fibre", "*")])

''' some code .... '''

################
#  Select ROI  #
################
fig, current_ax = pl.subplots()                    # make a new plotingrange
cadre = []
pl.imshow(Image, interpolation='none')
# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(current_ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1,3], # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       rectprops = dict(facecolor='red',
                                           edgecolor ='white',
                                           alpha =0.2,
                                           fill = True),
                                         )
pl.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
pl.title('Select ROI and press \'Enter\'')
pl.show()

print "After closing"
```

Here the purpose is to have a blocking window from pyplot until press keys 'Q' or 'enter' or close window. There is a n issue when I use Tkinter the window close but `"After closing"` is not displayed (program seems to block). 
I tried to replace `pl.show()` by `fig.show()` but it's not the same function so the window does not block and program continue.

NB: it works almost well if I remove :

```
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

An empty window appears in this case and I have to close it for good working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I actually need to destroy my object :

```
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [("Image fibre", "*")])
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pl.show()` launch the mainloop of Tk. And so, never return until you exit the loop.

To do so you have to register to the close event of the figure and quit the mainloop :

```
def on_close(event):
    root.quit()

''' some code ...'''

fig, current_ax = pl.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', on_close)

''' some code ...'''

pl.show()
print "After closing"
```